# Integration No.23 Part 3°)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

[image: part 3]
I'm going insane, this equality can't be proved!! I tried the other way back... It didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using by parts integration, we get

$$2n(I_{n-1}-I_n)=$$

$$2\int_0^1 nx^{n-1}(1-x)^{\frac 32}dx=$$

$$2\left( \left [x^n(1-x)^\frac 32 \right]_0^1 +\frac 32I_n\right)=$$

$$3I_n$$

qed.

thus

$$I_n=\frac{2n}{2n+3}I_{n-1}$$

$$=\frac{(2n)(2n-2)....4.2 }{(2n+3)(2n+1)...7.5 }I_0$$
with

$$I_0=\int_0^1\sqrt{1-x}dx=\frac 23 \left[-(1-x)^{\frac 32}\right]_0^1=\frac 23$$.

Comment: True, I solved it also again in another way. It worked .

Comment: Do you know the answer of part 4? So I can check it out

Comment: I didn't know how. Can you show me it please as a new answer. I tried $In=2n/(2n+3)In_-1$ then $In_-1=2n/(2n+3)In_-2$ ...

Comment: Is there a constant value for $In$? I'm trying to find a constant value

Comment: I mean Can it be written the form of a sum of arithmetic sequences?

Comment: @AbedShaar No. it's like expression of Integral of WALLIS. google it.

Comment: Aha. Thanks alot